# Write an generator/iterator expression for this sequence

Tags: python, enumerate

I have this exercise that I fail to understand

Suppose we are given a list X of integers. We need to construct a sequence of indices (positions) of the elements in this list equal to the maximal element. The indicies in the sequence are in the ascending order.

Hint use the enumerator function

```
from typing import Iterator
X = [1,10,3,4,10,5]
S : Iterator[int] = YOUR_EXPRESSION
assert list(S)==[1,4]
```

This is the only thing I could come up with, but for sure it does not return [1,4]

If you wondering what I don't understand, it is not clear from reading the description how it could return [1,4].

Maybe you want to try to explain that to me first...

This is my (wrong) solution

```
my_enumerate=enumerate (X)
my_enumerate=(list(my_enumerate))
my_enumerate.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: First solve how to find the maximum value in the list without mutating (sorting) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the list X containing `[1,10,3,4,10,5]`. The maximal, or largest, element is 10. Which means we should return a list of all the indices where we find 10. There are two 10s at index 1 and 4 respectively.

Using enumerate you get at each iteration the index and element. You can use that to filter out the elements you don't need. List comprehensions are useful in this case, allowing for filtering with the if syntax i.e. `[val for val in items if some_condition]`

Comment: ok that something to work with but why it says The indicies in the sequence are in the ascending order.

Comment: It seems overly specific. I guess enumerating, then sorting the values and only keeping the largest ones could cause the indices to be out of order and "break" the rule.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a generator like this

```
max_val=max(X)
s = (i for i, v in enumerate(X) if v==max_val)
```

Comment: This will be more efficient if you pre-calculate `max` once, rather than on each iteration through the list.

Comment: @match edited. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This requires two steps:

- Determine the maximum value with `max`
- Iterate the indices of your list and retain those that have this maximum value

To avoid a bad time complexity, it is necessary to not repeat the first step:

```
S : Iterator[int] = (lambda mx: 
    (i for i, x in enumerate(X) if x == mx)
)(max(X))
```

The reason for presenting the code in such ugly expression, is that in the question it seems a requirement to follow the template, and only alter the part that is marked with "YOUR_EXPRESSION".

This is not how you would write it without such artificial constraints. You would just do `mx = max(X)` and then assign the iterator to `S` in the next statement without the need for this inline lambda.

Comment: Oh jeeze, why not just do `mx = max(X)`?

Comment: Because in the question it was suggested that the boiler plate code had to be followed, with the part to fill in being `YOUR_EXPRESSION`... I didn't vote for that template ;-)

Comment: Ahhh I see. I suspect it would be better to explain that normally you would just do `mx = max(X)` but that the template constraints prevent you from writing idiomatic code

Comment: And that is now documented in the comments. But I also added it to my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
( x[0] for x in enumerate (X) if x[1] == max(X) )
```

this is the book solution

```
(i for (i, n) in enumerate(X) if n == max(X))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `max(X)` is recalculated for each iteration over `X`. This makes it inefficient. The book should mention this and offer the improved version where `max(X)` is only evaluated once.